# Ambiguity of if-clause

Tags: ambiguity, conditionals, independent-clauses

I'm not an English speaker, so my question might seem a little bit weird, but I'm truly confused. I saw some other cases like this one, which caused me to question what they really meant.

There's a reading challenge in a social platform, and the tasks are:

> 1) Set and share a reading goal
>
> 2) Share if goal was met

**My question**: Should I share only when I meet the reading goal, or should I share nonetheless, even when I don't meet the goal?

Comment: _Meet_ doesn't work intransitively in that sense; the last clause should be _even when I don't meet the goal?_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question. The reason this wording is confusing is because, in this context, the word *if* actually means *whether*. It would be more clearly reworded as:

- *Share whether the goal was met*

You should share in either case, and inform the appropriate person/people if you did complete the goal, or if you did not complete the goal.

Note that this use of the word *if* is not uncommon, but it is certainly ambiguous. Good luck!